# two problems in stack building program

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, stack

The following program successfully builds up a `stack` , but the 2 operations `pop` and `stack top` are giving exception and wrong result respectively. Here is the program :

```
// Working with stack using Array

/*
 * @author Suhail Gupta
 *
 */
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char choice;
int *ptrToArray; // this will be a pointer to the array alias stack that we'll make
int stackSize;
int currentStackSize = 0;
int *firstElement = NULL; // this pointer stores the address of the first element in the stack. It initially points to NULL
void push();
void pop();
void stackTop();

int main() {

cout << "Enter the size of stack : ";
cin >> stackSize;
ptrToArray = new int[stackSize];

do {
     push();
    cout << "Push elements ? y/n ";
    cin >> choice;
} while( choice == 'y');

cout << endl << "pop elements ? y/n ";
cin >> choice;
if( choice == 'y') {
    pop();
}

cout << endl << "know the stack top ? y/n ";
cin >> choice;
if( choice == 'y') {
    stackTop();
}
 }

void push() {

if( currentStackSize == stackSize) {        // check before pushing if the stack is full
    cout << endl << "Stack-Overflow !";
} else {
    int numberToPush;
    cout << endl << "Enter the number to be pushed : ";
    cin >> numberToPush;
    firstElement = &numberToPush; // Store the address of the Last number inserted.This is the address of the first element in the stack
    ptrToArray[currentStackSize] = numberToPush;
    cout << "The element you just inserted : " << ptrToArray[currentStackSize] << endl;
    currentStackSize++;     
 }    
}

void pop() {
if( stackSize == 0 ) {
    cout << "Stack Underflow !";
} else {
    delete firstElement; // delete the memory allocated to the first element
    firstElement = &ptrToArray[currentStackSize-1];
    currentStackSize--;
 }
}

void stackTop() {
if( firstElement == NULL) {
    cout << endl << "Stack Underflow !" << endl;
} else {
    cout << "The first element in the stack is : " << *firstElement;
  }
}
```

The pushing operation works fine.But if i call the `pop` function the following message is displayed :

[image]

### Second question :

Now just comment the statement where `pop` function gets called . The result that i get when trying to know the first element on the stack by calling the function `stackTop()` is `The first element in the stack is : -858993460` . This is some `garbage number` that i didn't enter while making up the `stack`. Why the statement `*firstElement` gives the wrong result then ?

Comment: I assume this is homework?  Is the class encouraging that style (many global variables, use of `new[]` instead of `std::vector`, helper functions responsible for both I/O and data structure management)?  Read about the Single Responsibility Principle, then find a better instructor.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt I have not read about `std::vector` yet in c++

Comment: Fine, so you learn about manual memory management.  That doesn't excuse use of global variables, or poor program organization that violates the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  The wikipedia explanation actually isn't all that good, because SRP is equally applicable to procedural (non-OO) designs, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: @ Ben Voigt I agree with poor program organization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *firstElement = NULL; // Global pointer variable
void push() {
 // ...    
    else {
        // ..
        int numberToPush;  // Resides on stack.
        // ....
        firstElement = &numberToPush; 
        // ...

    } // numberToPush cease to exist from this point.
}
```

`numberToPush` is a local variable and have a blocked scope to `else` part and you are taking the reference of it.This is resulting you the garbage.

Edit: You need to understand that storage duration of global variables are different to that of local. Just taking the reference of local to a global variable doesn't increase the life time of a local variable. As soon as it's scope finishes, the variable ceases to exist.

Comment: but `firstElement` is a global variable. Will it not retain the address ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `delete` on individual array elements. One `new[]` must be matched by precisely one `delete[]`.

Comment: then how can i `delete` the first element of the stack ?

Comment: You can't. Just `delete[]` the whole array when `currentStackSize==0`.

Comment: @ MSalters So i should just change the `firstElement` pointer to the second element _(from the top in the stack)_ during pop operation ?

Comment: @Suhail: Eh, I'd do something else. Notice that you (1) have another problem, namely that `push` doesn't do the reverse, and (2), `firstElement` is redundant anyway. It's far easier to just use `ptrToArray[currentStackSize]` in `stackTop()`. And that's currently the only place where you use it. Oh, and think about what happens if you push one element and then pop 2.

Answer (score 1):

easy...

in your push you did:

```
firstElement = &numberToPush;
```

which make firstElement to get the address of the local variable which will be delete as the function quit.
change it to:

```
firstElement = ptrToArray[currentStackSize];
```

AND you can't delete a single var in an array.
You should delete the entire array in the end of Main()

Just remove the VAR firstElement - it's useless.
And do that:

```
void push() {  

    if( currentStackSize == stackSize) {        // check before pushing if the stack is full

        cout << endl << "Stack-Overflow !";  
    } else {

        int numberToPush;  
        cout << endl << "Enter the number to be pushed : ";  
        cin >> numberToPush;  
        ptrToArray[currentStackSize] = numberToPush;  
        cout << "The element you just inserted : " << ptrToArray[currentStackSize] << endl;  
        currentStackSize++;      
    }      
}  

void pop() { 

    if( stackSize == 0 ) { 

        cout << "Stack Underflow !";  
    } else {  

        currentStackSize--;  
    }  
}  

void stackTop() {  
    cout << "The first element in the stack is : " << ptrToArray[currentStackSize];  
}
```

Comment: but `firstElement` is a global variable. Will it not retain the address ? Why?

Comment: it will retain the address, but the address itself is not valid. Performing 'delete' on it is not a valid operation.

Comment: It will still have the address. But it will have an address for a variable no longer exists.

Comment: Add some fixes for your code here, not sure it fixes everything but it a start.

Answer (score 1):

firstElement is pointing to a variable on the stack: numberToPush. When numberToPush goes out of context, the firstElement pointer becomes invalid. Which is why your pointer crashes when delete is called